# How to add www. to domain with NginX and SSL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx

I have a VPS with a Rails 4 app running on Ubuntu with NginX and Unicorn.

Since I want all pages to be SSL secured, all requests to `http://` are forwarded to `https://` which is working fine.

This is my NginX configuration:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css text/comma-separated-values;
        upstream app_server { server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0; }

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        server {
                listen 80;
                server_name myapp.com;
                rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
        }

        server {
                listen 443;
                server_name myapp.com;
                root /home/rails/public;
                index index.htm index.html;

                ssl on;
                ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/myapp.com.crt;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/myapp.com.key;

                location / {
                        try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
                }

                location @app {
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_pass http://app_server;
                 }
        }
}
```

How can I make it that all requests to `http://myapp.com` and `https://myapp.com` are forwarded to `https://www.myapp.com`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can go about this two ways:

- In your Rails app, detect if the requested URI contains a `www` and give a 30(1|2) redirect based on that (probably easiest).
- Create an additional vhost in Nginx listening on `myapp.com` and only have it do redirects to `www.myapp.com`.

  server {
    listen 443;
    server_name myapp.com;
    [add ssl config]
    return 301 https://www.myapp.com$request_uri;
  }

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess your second solution will be faster, no? Sorry about my n00bishness but where exactly in my code above will I have to place your code?